# Automated introduction of mutation at a specific base in a DNA sequence

Tags: excel, vba, dna-sequence

I am looking for a way to change A ->T and G ->C and vice versa at the 11th base in a 30-base DNA sequence. I have tried to use the Replace function in Excel but I couldn't work out how to make it conditional i.e. if it is A change it to T and so on.

I need to do this in hundreds of sequences, each only 30 bp long. I want to automate this using Excel macro (or function). I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Please include what you have tried. Also include some example input data and desired output data. You telling us *"specific location in a DNA sequence"* is actually very unspecific. Be more precise with your explanation. Also see [mcve]. As broad as your question is now I see no chance that this can be answered at all (even I'm familiar with bioinformatics).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. I am looking for a way to change A ->T and G ->C and vice versa at the 11th base in a 30-base DNA sequence.

I have tried to use the Replace function in Excel but I couldn't work out how to make it conditional i.e. if it is A change it to T and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I have now managed to find a solution. The following formula seem to work.

```
=REPLACE(A1,11,1,IFS(MID(A1,11,1)="C","g",MID(A1,11,1)="G","c",MID(A1,11,1)="T","a",MID(A1,11,1)="A","t"))
```